# Python SQLAlchemy: psycopg2.ProgrammingError relation already exists?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, runtime-error, psycopg2

I have repeatable tried to create a table `MYTABLENAME` with SQLAlchemy in Python. I deleted all tables through my SQL client Dbeaver but I am getting an error that the table exists such that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hhh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/hhh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "ix_MYTABLENAME_index" already exists

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "ix_MYTABLENAME_index" already exists
 [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX "ix_MYTABLENAME_index" ON "MYTABLENAME" (index)']
```

I succeed in the creation of tables and their insertions with an unique name but the second time I am getting the error despite deleting the tables in Dbeaver.

**Small example**

```
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def storePandasDF2PSQL(myDF_):
    #Store results as Pandas Dataframe to PostgreSQL database.
    #
    #Example
    #df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    #dbName= date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")+"_TABLE"
    #engine = create_engine('postgresql://hhh:yourPassword@localhost:1234/hhh')
    #df.to_sql(dbName, engine)

    df      = myDF_
    dbName  = date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")+"_TABLE"
    engine  = create_engine('postgresql://hhh:yourPassword@localhost:1234/hhh')
    # ERROR: NameError: name 'table' is not defined
    #table.declarative_base.metadata.drop_all(engine)    #Drop all tables

    #TODO: This step is causing errors because the SQLAlchemy thinks the 
    #TODO: table still exists even though deleted
    df.to_sql(dbName, engine)
```

**What is the proper way to clean up the backend such as some hanging index in order to recreate the table with fresh data? In other words, how to solve the error?**

Comment: Are you certain the table has actually been dropped? In PostgreSQL: `DROP TABLE always removes any indexes, rules, triggers, and constraints that exist for the target table.` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html)

Comment: @Nicarus I can list the tables with `\c myDB`, `\dt` and `\dt *` where I cannot see the table so I think it is properly dropped, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be from sqlalchemy side which believes that there is an index as message of deletion of tables was not notified to the sqlalchemy. There is a sqlalchemy way of deleting the tables

```
table.declarative_base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

This should keep Sqlalchemy informed about the deletions.

Comment: Is "table" a placeholder for the name of the table? `>>> table.declarative_base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'table' is not defined`, I will try again.

Comment: A table is an object which is a subset of metadata.So it will drop only that table using drop_all()

Comment: So with a table called `MYTABLENAME`, you have to use `MYTABLENAME.declarative_base.metadata.drop_all(engine)` in python where the functions `declarative_base`, `metadata` and `drop_all` are from the `sqlalchemy` package?

Comment: Actually MYTABLENAME is ORM_class mapped to your table but can access from table as well. All you need is to know metadata of the table.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#create-a-schema. Look for heading Declare a Mapping in the documentation.

Comment: Can you add a small working example about what you mean? I add a small example to Q where I store a pandas dataframe into the PSQL db where SQLAlchemy is firing the error, apparently because thinking that the table still exists.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer does not address the reusing of the same table names and hence not about cleaning up the SQLAlchemy metadata.*

Instead of reusing the table names, add the execution time like this to the end of the tableName

```
import time 
dbName  = date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")+"_TABLE_"+str(time.time())
dbTableName = dbName
```

so your SQL developmnet environment, such as SQL client locking up the connection or specific tables, does not matter that much. Closing Dbeaver can help while running the Python with SQLAlchemy.